# While giving the command - python manage.py runserver, it shows the given error

Tags: django

Error while executing python manage.py runserver

`enter code here`    Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File 
   "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\threading.py", 
    line 917, in _bootstrap_inner

```
  self.run()
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception        
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_filters\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .filterset import FilterSet
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_filters\filterset.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django_filters import filterset, rest_framework
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django_filters\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .filterset import FilterSet
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filterset.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .filters import (
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filters.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.constants import QUERY_TERMS
ImportError: cannot import name 'QUERY_TERMS' from 'django.db.models.sql.constants' (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\iam_orm_layer\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\constants.py)
```

Comment: which version of django are you using?

Comment: Update Django filter 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here:

[Could not import QUERY_TERMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158204/could-not-import-query-terms)

The constant you are trying to import does not exist in the django filters version you are using