# Could not import QUERY_TERMS

Tags: python, django

I am running a website through `Python` and `Django`.

```
Django-filters=2.1 installed
Django=2.1 installed
```

When I run, I'm getting the below error.

```
importError: Could not import 'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend' for API setting 'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS'. 
ImportError: cannot import name 'QUERY_TERMS' from 
'django.db.models.sql.constants' (C:\Users\Android V\AppData\Loc
    al\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\constants.
    py).
```

Comment: Related: https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/956 You probably better work with `django-filter-2.2`

Comment: Kindly Update your Django filters

Comment: It looks like you did not use django-filter-2.1, can you show the output of `pip freeze` (of your virtual environment)?

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**: upgrade your [django-filter](/questions/tagged/django-filter) package (not to be confused with the [django](/questions/tagged/django) package) to the latest version.

The reason this fails is because in Django there has been a [changeset [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/commit/244cc401559e924355cf943b6b8e66ccf2f6da3a#diff-112486a821c7f63d1ab955c6bb2b4db8) that indeed removed the `QUERY_TERMS` constant from the `django.db.models.sql.constants`, to allow the `ModelAdmin` to use *any* lookup. This changes has been deployed in [django-2.1](/questions/tagged/django-2.1) (so in [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), there was still a `QUERY_TERMS` constant).

The [django-filter-1.1.0](/questions/tagged/django-filter-1.1.0) package still used that constant. This is fixed in a [changeset [GitHub]](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/commit/bda9aca2d89383a79c76b04cde2edb705beb1a07#diff-62675bd4657a4dec4674376fae1bf3a2L7), and as of [django-filter-2.0.0](/questions/tagged/django-filter-2.0.0), this is no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

My case in centos7 shows the error:

File "/root/wangxq/python/vidly/api/models.py", line 2, in 
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/vidly-j9gvS3wP/lib/python3.9/site- packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 32, in 
from django.db.models.sql.constants import QUERY_TERMS
ImportError: cannot import name 'QUERY_TERMS' from 'django.db.models.sql.constants' (/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/vidly-j9gvS3wP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/constants.py)

### [image]

To solve:

edit the file "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/vidly-j9gvS3wP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", and add try block to the line "from django.db.models.sql.constants import QUERY_TERMS" as follows:

```
try:
    from django.db.models.sql.constants import QUERY_TERMS
except ImportError:
    QUERY_TERMS = {
      'exact', 'iexact', 'contains', 'icontains', 'gt', 'gte', 'lt', 'lte', 'in', 'startswith', 'istartswith', 'endswith', 'iendswith', 'range', 'year','month', 'day', 'week_day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'isnull', 'search','regex', 'iregex',
   }
```